# Jquery UI sortable order for two different containers while DRAG and DROP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have two different containers for my video editor. One container is used for maintaining the video thumbnails those are uploaded by the users. I have done a drag and drop inside the same container and updated the orders in DB for my future by using the following script

```
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    j$132('#page .sortable-list').sortable({
                        update: function(event, ui) {
                            var order = [];
                            $('#image-list li').each(function(e) {
                                order.push($(this).attr('id') + '=' + ($(this).index() + 1));
                            });
                            var positions = order.join(';')
                        },
                        connectWith: '#page .sortable-list',
                        placeholder: 'placeholder',
                    });
                });
            </script>
<ul id="image-list" class="sortable-list">

                        </ul>
```

But now my problem is have to maintain two different drag and drop containers with individual orders and also those should have interconnection between them.I have done the drag and drop but could not get the order ids individually.Those are getting conflict.

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/qvbCr)

You don't need to loop through the sortable elements manually, jquery UI's `.sortable()` has a  [toArray](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray) method which will return an array of their IDs by default.

If you use this method it will be easier to tell the lists apart, since you can just listen for their changes individually. If only one list changes, the `update` handler will fire once, if an element is dragged from one list to the other, it will fire for both lists.

```
$('.sortable-list').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sortable-list',
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var changedList = this.id;
    var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
  }
});
```

Either way, you will need to give the lists some identifying property to tell them apart, like an ID. You can then use this ID and the new list element positions information to update your DB.